# in my code there is an error how to solve it

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

What's wrong with my code

```
<?php 
session_start();
require_once('koneksi.php');
$username = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];
$cekuser = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$username'");
$hasil = mysqli_fetch_array($cekuser);
if(mysqli_num_rows($cekuser) == 0) {
    echo "<div align='center'>Username Belum Terdaftar! <a href='login.php'>Back</a></div>;
} else{
  if($pass<>$hasil['$username]'){
    echo "<div align='center'>Password Salah! <a href='login.php'>Back</a></div>;
 }  else{
    $_SESSION['username']=$hasil['username'];
    header('location:index.php');
  }
}

?>
```

I get an error message like this

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /storage/emulated/0/htdocs/proseslogin.php on line 11

Comment: Check for missing quote

Answer (score -1):

You are missing a closing quote here

```
echo "<div align='center'>Username Belum Terdaftar! <a href='login.php'>Back</a></div>;
```

And here

```
echo "<div align='center'>Password Salah! <a href='login.php'>Back</a></div>;
```

You need to close off your quotes

```
echo "<div align='center'>Username Belum Terdaftar! <a href='login.php'>Back</a></div>";

echo "<div align='center'>Password Salah! <a href='login.php'>Back</a></div>";
```